# preg_replace isnt working

Tags: php, preg-replace, output, echo

I am running the following code:

```
$filename = 'bla.mp4';
    echo preg_replace('/\.(m4a|wav|ogg|flac|avi|flv|mov|wmv|m3u|mid|wma|webm|mkv|asf|mp(\d+)|aif(?:f?)|3gp(?:p?)|mp(eg(\d+)?|g(\d+)?))/g', '', $filename);
```

However I get no output, surely it would echo 'bla' but it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP PCRE patterns do not support the `g` modifier, [and as the manual states](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> Spaces and newlines are ignored in modifiers, **other characters cause error.**

As an error is caused, [`preg_replace` works as expected](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise subject will be returned unchanged **or NULL if an error occurred.**

You have probably disabled or suppressed warnings in your code, which you should never, ever do during development (and always in production). Check whether `display_errors` is enabled in your php.ini file, and/or whether you have any `error_reporting(...)` calls in your code.

Answer (score 2):

That code gives `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g' in /home/abe/http/htdocs/tmp/test.php on line 3` for me. Works fine if I remove the trailing `g`.